# linux network drivers --- net_device_ops

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

so far i have only used file operational structure in device driver.
Using system call open & read , write.

How to open device driver & transmit data using net_device_ops  ?
Is there reference example on net for the user program to interact with it ?

http://lnxpps.de/rpie/mcp2515_mod.c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, so let me know if my answer doesn't make sense.

I see you have defined functions for `.ndo_open`, `.ndo_stop`, and `.ndo_start_xmit`.  `.ndo_open` is called by the kernel when you configure the interface using `ifconfig up` or use ifconfig to assign an address to the interface.  `.ndo_stop` is called by the kernel when you remove the module or if you shutdown the interface using `ifconfig down`.

ifconfig is described here:  http://linux.die.net/man/8/ifconfig

`.ndo_start_xmit` is called by the kernel network stack when a socket is used to transmit a packet.  So, to transmit data using `.ndo_start_xmit` you'll need to create a socket, assign an appropriate destination address, and send the data via the socket.  If you're using IP, there are tools you can use send packets easily, such as netperf or iperf.